# Problem with implementing method to sort with using comparer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

I have implemented a method to SortBy TResult type, but unfortunately my solution is not good enough and unit tests are not passed. Should I implement this with using order by with IComparer, or probably by Array.Sort, or with swapping in loop ? Please about help and explanation, why my ideas are not suitable in this case. I would be grateful.

```
        public static TSource[] SortBy<TSource>(this TSource[] source, IComparer<TSource> comparer)
        {
            if (source is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (source == Array.Empty<TSource>())
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(source));
            }

            if (comparer is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));
            }

            Array.Sort(source, (a, b) => a == null ? 1 : b == null ? -1 : comparer.Compare(a, b));

            var result = source.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x == null).ToArray();
            return result;
        }
```

EDITED:
I want to sort the objects in this method. If a members of this array is a string I want to sort this starting from nulls, after from small letters, after by big letters and last criterium is a string.length, sorting by value of integers is easy, but for string lengths is more difficult, because all the time the result is bad, because once I sort it almost well, I have the same length strings in reverse, but I have uppercase letters before lowercase.

Comment: Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0. The orderBy method needs to have a keyselector and comparer. I dont understand why there is a necessity to create a Sortby extension method though.

Comment: So "I've written some code that is wrong, figure out what I'm trying to do by reading it, and tell me how to fix it"? - it'd be easier if you just told us exactly what you're trying to do. "I'm trying to sort an array" is not exact. "I have an array of people and I want to sort the males by age descending and the females by height ascending, and I want them interleaved male/female/male/female etc" is exact

Comment: @CaiusJard Now I have changed my code, I have a problem with sorting strings with their string.length, I want to do method which return at first nulls, after lowercase letters, after uppercase letters, for example, I will expect that 'i' will be returned before 'I', and last criterium is string.Length

Comment: Length how? Shorter first?